# WKInterfaceLabel multiple lines in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, watchkit, apple-watch

I am making an app for Apple Watch in Xamarin. I have a `WKInterfaceLabel` in my table row. I can display text, but I would like it on 2 lines (if there's not enough space to fit it on 1 line). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it: for people using Xamarin, right-click on your storyboard file, and open it in Xcode Interface Builder. Click on the the label, and set the "Lines" property to 2 (or more). And make sure the size of it is set to "Size to fit content", same with any parent container/group.